# Strange write speed for mdadm RAID0

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have just set up mdadm for RAID0 with two 5400rpm 2.5'' HDDs.

By performing a write speed test using dd:

> dd if=/dev/zero of=./largefile bs=1M count=3000

I get:

> 3000+0 records in
>
> 3000+0 records out
>
> 3145728000 bytes (3.1 GB, 2.9GiB) copied, 0.986443 s, 3.2 GB/s

which obviously doesn't make sense - tested with copying and opening files, the drive does work all right though.

Anyone knows what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **oflag=sync** option and you'll see relevant speeds:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=./largefile bs=1M count=3000 oflag=sync`

Answer (score 0):

Just as a comparison for my single NMVe M.2 SSD:

```sh
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=./largefile bs=1M count=3000
3000+0 records in
3000+0 records out
3145728000 bytes (3.1 GB, 2.9 GiB) copied, 1.98838 s, 1.6 GB/s

$ dd if=/dev/zero of=./largefile bs=1M count=3000 oflag=sync
3000+0 records in
3000+0 records out
3145728000 bytes (3.1 GB, 2.9 GiB) copied, 23.9874 s, 131 MB/s

$ time cp -a ./largefile ./largefile2

real    0m4.738s
user    0m0.021s
sys     0m2.811s
```

The file is 3 GB / 4.738 seconds = 633 MB/sec. So `dd` is wrong measuring stick in each test scenario. I would use `cp` as the real world test.